# Bulk creating objects with nested attributes in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

We are encountering a problem in a new app we are creating.
We have two models: Packages and products, a package has many products.
We need to create a controller that can bulk create packages so we started using the activerecord-import gem which allows for bulk creates. However the problem is that the gem does not allow for the use of nested attributes to create products, which means I cannot create the corresponding products for each package.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem or have any potential elegant solutions?

The JSON for the controller would be similar as below.

```
{
  packages: [
    {
      weight: 'x',
      products_attributes: [
        {
          code: x
        },
        {
          code: x
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      weight: 'y',
      products_attributes: [
        {
          code: y
        },
        {
          code: y
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
books = 10.times.map do |i|
  book = Book.new(name: "book #{i}")
  book.reviews.build(title: "Excellent")
  book 
end
Book.import books, recursive: true
```

You can try this, iterate your hash, and build objects for packages, and for each package, iterate products, and build products objects assigned to package object.
Another way - is build raw SQL, but it's harder

Comment: Hi, thanks so much this worked perfectly and executes in only two SQL statements, thank you again!

Comment: Update: I found with just adding ```recursive: true``` to the import I did not need to do the build step done in the map

Comment: What happen if author is a belongs_to association and you want it to create author on books if it doesn't exist?
e.g.
`books = 10.times.map do |i|
  book = Book.new(name: "Book Name #{i}")
  book.author = Author.new(name: "John Doe")
  book 
end
Book.import books, recursive: true`
This code above doesn't create the Author if it doesn't exist even if you set accept_nested_attributes :author on Book model. Do you have any idea how to go about this?

Comment: recursive flag only works in PostgreSQL. It doesn't works with MySQL.